# The probability of $\;-g(x)< f(x,y) <g(x)\; $? knowing that both LHS and RHS inequalities occur with the same probability.

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I have an inequality for two random variables $x,y$
$$-g(x)< f(x,y) <g(x) \qquad (1)$$
where $g(x)>0$.

The probability of each part of the inequality $(1)$ is the same, say $\alpha$
$$ P[\;-g(x)< f(x,y)\;]=P[\;f(x,y) <g(x)\;]=\alpha$$

Having known this data, are we able to determine the probability that the inequality $(1)$ holds?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, since $g>0$, the events $A=[f(x,y)\ge g(x)]$ and $B=[f(x,y)\le -g(x)]$ are mutually exclusive, with probabilities $1-\alpha$ each, and the event you are interested in is $C=(A\cup B)^c$. Therefore,
$$
P(C)=1-P(A\cup B)=1-2(1-\alpha)=2\alpha-1.
$$